# What are the properties of the titleFont in Dojo charting?

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.charting

What are the properties of the chart title in dojo charting?

titleFont: "normal normal normal 15pt Arial"

What do the "normal" tags refer to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be in following order I believe

```
   normal      normal       normal       15pt        Arial
```

---

```
font-style  font-variant  font-weight  font-size  font-family
```

For more info **[check this out](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font)**